# Schedule data purge job using Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, purge

I have an Apache Camel microservice that reads data from Kafka and
writes it DB.

- I want to write a purge job that deletes the data older
  than N days from DB.
- The only thing is, DB contains a variety of data and each type of data may have a different purge schedule. Also, the type of data keeps on increasing day by day.

Is Apache Camel designed to implement such scheduler jobs? Is it good practice to use Camel Scheduler to write purge jobs?

Answer (score 1):

[From Apache camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/what-is-camel.html)

Apache Camel ™ is a versatile open-source integration framework based on known Enterprise Integration Patterns.

Since Data Purging is not an Enterprise Pattern, we can understand that Apache Camel is not built for this.

The best way is to impliment Partioning policies at the Database side. [Please refer this](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/eips/enterprise-integration-patterns.html)